# click to open and close paragraph in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create some paragraphs but user has to click to open paragraph from first line. Like plus and minus sign in the first line to open and close. Is there any simple way to do in asp.net / c#

Comment: You probably don't want to implement this in C#. Most likely (though depending on your exact requirements), your user experience will be better if you do this in JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: use .slideToggle() in jQuery